# Search data in a VERY LARGE XML FEED using PHP

Tags: php, xml

http://www.topbuy.com.au/tbcart/tbadmin/datafeed/shoppingcom.xml

This is my feed url which never opens in browser or takes hours to open it.

I want to create PHP page where i want to put a searchbox ( where i will put  ) in my PHP page and once hit submit my PHP code should search and display corresponding products PRICE.

So shall i use SimpleXML for this or any other recommendations ?

```
<Products>
<Product><MPN><![CDATA[INK-PE-009]]></MPN><Manufacturer><![CDATA[Epson]]></Manufacturer><ProductName><![CDATA[Epson T009 Colour Compatible Inkjet Cartridge]]></ProductName><ProductURL><![CDATA[http://www.topbuy.com.au/tbcart/pc/Epson-T009-Colour-Compatible-Inkjet-Cartridge-p3343.htm?utm_source=TopBuy_ShoppingCom&utm_content=&utm_medium=cpc&dismode=1&utm_campaign=TBDF-XX10421]]></ProductURL><ProductType><![CDATA[Compatible Ink Cartridges]]></ProductType><ImageURL><![CDATA[http://www2.topbuy.com.au/tbcart/pc/catalog/General/TBDF-XX10421_1.jpg]]></ImageURL><Price>4.09</Price><OriginalPrice>9</OriginalPrice><Category><![CDATA[Consumables->Compatible Ink Cartridges]]></Category><ProductDescription><![CDATA[$4.05 Cash Price see store for detailsRelated Brand  EpsonOriginal Cartridge Equivalent T009Related Printers STYLUS 1270, STYLUS 1280, STYLUS 1290, STYLUS 3300C, STYLUS PHOTO 1270, STYLUS PHOTO 1290, STYLUS PHOTO 1290 silverThis cartridge works in the following printers  Epson Stylus Photo 1270/1280Please check the name (code) of the cartridge in your printer before ordering to ensure that it matches the name of the cartridges you are ordering from us. In some instances a printer can take more than one cartridge type and ...]]></ProductDescription><Stock>Y</Stock><ShippingCost>10</ShippingCost><StockDescription>No.1 OZ SUPERSTORE AUS WARRANTY FAST SHIPPING</StockDescription><Condition>Brand New</Condition></Product>
<Product><MPN><![CDATA[INK-PE-013]]></MPN><Manufacturer><![CDATA[Epson]]></Manufacturer><ProductName><![CDATA[Epson T013 Black Compatible Inkjet Cartridge]]></ProductName><ProductURL><![CDATA[http://www.topbuy.com.au/tbcart/pc/Epson-T013-Black-Compatible-Inkjet-Cartridge-p3345.htm?utm_source=TopBuy_ShoppingCom&utm_content=&utm_medium=cpc&dismode=1&utm_campaign=TBDF-XX10423]]></ProductURL><ProductType><![CDATA[Compatible Ink Cartridges]]></ProductType><ImageURL><![CDATA[http://www2.topbuy.com.au/tbcart/pc/catalog/General/TBDF-XX10423_1.jpg]]></ImageURL><Price>2.09</Price><OriginalPrice>5</OriginalPrice><Category><![CDATA[Consumables->Compatible Ink Cartridges]]></Category><ProductDescription><![CDATA[$2.07 Cash Price see store for detailsRelated Brand  EpsonOriginal Cartridge Equivalent T013Related Printers STYLUS COLOR 480, STYLUS COLOR 580, STYLUS COLOR C20, STYLUS COLOR C40, STYLUS COLOUR 480, STYLUS COLOUR 580, STYLUS COLOUR C20UX, STYLUS COLOUR C40SX, STYLUS COLOUR C40UXThis cartridge works in the following printers  Epson Stylus Colour 480/580Please check the name (code) of the cartridge in your printer before ordering to ensure that it matches the name of the cartridges you are ordering from us. In some instances a ...]]></ProductDescription><Stock>Y</Stock><ShippingCost>10</ShippingCost><StockDescription>No.1 OZ SUPERSTORE AUS WARRANTY FAST SHIPPING</StockDescription><Condition>Brand New</Condition></Product>
```

Comment: I've heard people refer to 2Mb as "very large", whereas other people use "very large" to mean 2Gb. Please give us real numbers. Otherwise it's like asking us to design a bridge to cross a "very wide" river.

Comment: @MichaelKay 69 MB is the size

Comment: OK, that's not particularly large by modern standards - XSLT or XQuery should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use the [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) class because it doesn't require to load the full xml into memory at once.

The downside is that you will have to implement searching and filtering by hand, for a simple name searching you can do something like this:

```
$reader = new XMLReader;
$reader->open('shoppingcom.xml');

while ($reader->read()) {
    if ($reader->name == 'Product') {
        $productxml = $reader->readOuterXML();
        while ($reader->read()) {
            if ($reader->name == 'ProductName' && stristr($reader->readInnerXML(), 'adidas')) {
                print $productxml;
                // now it contains the <Product>...</Product> fragment of the xml
                // you can use simplexml on this fragment, or just add an if for Prize node
            }
            if ($reader->name == 'Product' && $reader->nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Still, the example feed is solid `64M`, you might have better results for live searching if you create a database for this that could index the fields you want to search for and returns the xml fragments, so you don't have to normalize everything to tables.